# How to select every thing til any character repeats using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select text till the linebreak (or any other) is repeated twice

I tried to stop selection with `[^\n]*?`

However, I like to do something that can select will two (or more) consecutive linebreaks are encountered

### used regex in JS

`/^(?!#{1,6}\s|\*\s|\d+.\s|!|\[|>+\s+|-|\|)([^\n]*?)\n{1,}$/gmi`

### dummy text

```
select this First in a single line



select this second one line

select these multiline paragraph
including this I want to select these 3 line in one paragraph
However only last line is selected in a group I am using [^\n]*?








# do not select anything below
> one line

> multiline paragraph
> secondline
> single



>> one line

>> multiline paragraph
>> secondline
>> single





# heading

---

|S.No|name|
|:---|---|---|
|1|prateek|

## headgin

* list

1. list

11. asdfli

![asdf](image)

[asd](heading)
```

### demo

https://regex101.com/r/s7nKFq/1

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing Markdown, please consider using a parser instead of regex. The following regex should only be used in case you have no other choice as it cannot guarantee a correct match for every possible situation.

```
^             # At the beginning of line, match
(?!\d+\.)     #                        and not a number followed by a dot,
[^[!|#>\n*-]  # not one of '[!|#>\n*-'                                     followed by
.+?           # one or more characters, as few as possible,
(?=(.)\1)     # all of which is succeeded by two repeated characters.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aGoMAL/1).

Answer (score 1):

`^(?!\s*$|#{1,6}\s|\*\s|\d+.\s|!|\[|>+|-|\|)([\s\S]*?)\n{2,}`

https://regex101.com/r/nrssCf/1

**explain**

`\s*$` match an empty line.

`\n{2,}` two or more linebreak.